# SharePoint PeoplePicker search not finding users

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker

I have a SharePoint site configured with FBA.

If I enter a user into a people picker field and check their name, it shows up fine:

[image: check names]

However, if I click the "Browse" button (show above to the right of Check Names) and search for a user, nothing comes up.

[image: browse]

I have the people picker wildcards on the web app set to

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
  <add key="SQL-MembershipProvider" value="*" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Which are the same as in Central Admin, where search seems to be working fine. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

After opening the tab in another browser window and opening the JavaScript console, I noticed several errors preventing the page JS from running.

[image]

I added the following to the handlers section of the web.config:

```
<add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

This resolved the issues with searching for users.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that some properties of people picker is not set for searching.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajank/archive/2009/09/01/all-you-want-to-know-about-people-picker-in-sharepoint-functionality-configuration-troubleshooting-part-1.aspx

the above article states "All about People Picker"

**Please go below link, it seems you have to set the search criteria and domain.**

**http://manojvnair.blogspot.ae/2014/04/users-do-not-show-up-in-sharepoint.html**

Are you able to get validated all users or specific user in people picker?